# View in ArcSDE 10.1 Problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, spatial-view

I have created a view by joining a feature layer and 2-3 other tables in ArcSDE database using help from 
[James Richard Post](http://www.jamesrichards.com/post/2009/07/16/How-To-Create-an-ArcSDE-Spatial-View-With-an-Outer-Join.aspx).  The view gets created fine in both SQL Server 2008 and also in SDE.  In SQL Server it shows records and geometry but when it comes to ArcGIS it does not show table or geometry in ArcGIS Desktop 10.1.
[image].
It shows only the geometry in ArcCatalog but not the table in preview table.

Below is my code:

```
SELECT SPE.[OBJECTID] ,SPE.[BaseId], SPE.[PlayId] , B.[BasinName], SP.[ShaleName], AGS.[AgeS],  SP.[Ref] , SPE.[Shape] , SPE.[Shape_STArea__], SPE.[Shape_STLength__]
    FROM [dbo].[Play] SPE inner join [dbo].[Base] B on SPE.[BaseId]=B.[OBJECTID]
        inner join [dbo].[shale] SP on SPE.[Shale]=SP.[OBJECTID]
        inner join [dbo].[Age] AGS on SPE.[AgeId]=AGS.[OBJECTID]
```